# PUB/SUB model of pyzmq not receiving messages inside a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to use the pyzmq **`PUB/SUB`** socket-archetypes inside a realm of **`multiprocessing.Process`**:

I have one subscriber:

```
import time
import collections    
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5000")

nb_recv = 0
begin = time.time()
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
while True:
    msg = socket.recv_json()
    print(msg)
```

And two different implementations of a publisher.

With this one, the subscriber **receives** the messages:

```
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process

class Sender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._context = zmq.Context()
        pass

    def run(self):
        self._socket = self._context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self._socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
        seq_num = 0
        while True:
            msg = { "sequence": seq_num }
            self._socket.send_json(msg)
            seq_num += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Sender()
    p = Process(target=s.run)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

But with this one ( where the only difference is that the creation of the **`socket`** is in the constructor, instead of being in the **`run()`** class-method ), the subscriber **does not receive** any message:

```
import zmq
from multiprocessing import Process

class Sender(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._context = zmq.Context()
        self._socket = self._context.socket(zmq.PUB) # <---------
        pass

    def run(self):
        self._socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
        seq_num = 0
        while True:
            msg = { "sequence": seq_num }
            self._socket.send_json(msg)
            seq_num += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Sender()
    p = Process(target=s.run)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

When I replace `multiprocessing.Process` by a **`threading.Thread`**, both classes work well, but I did not find any explanation on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the object in one process and trying to execute a method of it in another.

It *is* possible to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868395/python-multiprocessing-object-passed-by-value) or even [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717109/python-class-object-sharing-between-processes-created-using-multiprocessing-modu) objects between `multiprocessing` processes with `multiprocessing.Manager` but since this object holds a non-shareable resource (a network socket), you're better off creating it inside the worker process unless you wish to walk the minefield of pickling and using an object with non-picklable fields.